# Scroll back the page where user clicked

Tags: jquery

I need to scroll back to the position where the user originally clicked. Following is the series of action

1. User scrolls down the page to click an item
2. On some action the user is taken back to top of the page
3. Again on some action user should be taken back to the same position where he/she originally clicked

Though I am able to take the user to original position, sometimes the selected item scroll all the way to top. It should scroll to the exact position where the user clicked. Thanks!

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).attr('data-scrollpos', pos);
  });
});

$('#back').click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 600);
});

$('#activePos').click(function() {
  var pos1 = $('li.active').attr('data-scrollpos');
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: pos1
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  width: 48%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.active {
  border: solid 1px orange;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <span id="back">Scroll to Top</span>
  <span id="activePos">Back to Active</span>
  <span id="position"></span>
</div>
```

Here's my Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kanappan/whfj9e50/81/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this line:

```
$(".active").removeClass("active");
```

Disable the active class on others when you set active class.

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).attr('data-scrollpos', pos);
  });
});

$('#back').click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 600);
});

$('#activePos').click(function() {
  var pos1 = $('li.active').attr('data-scrollpos');
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: pos1
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  width: 48%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.active {
  border: solid 1px orange;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <span id="back">Scroll to Top</span>
  <span id="activePos">Back to Active</span>
  <span id="position"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The challenge is not to remove the .active class. It's all about scrolling back to the position where .active class is present. try clicking the "scroll to top" and "back to active" links.